# Periodic Fuctions - Signals -

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, signal-processing

If, in the periods, the two half's signal periodic have the same form and opposite phases, the periodic signal has symmetry of half wave. If the periodic signal $g(t)$, of period $T_0$, satisfy the condition of symmetry of half wave, so:

$g(t-\frac{T_0}{2}) = -g(t)$

In this case, proof that all the harmonics (coefficient) of even order are NULL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the function $g(t)$ has Fourier series coefficient of $a_k$ for the harmonic $e^{i2\pi k/T_0}$, $k$ are integers from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$.

$g\left(t-\frac{T_0}{2}\right)$ is a time-shifted function of $g(t)$, and has corresponding Fourier series coefficients of $a_k e^{-i\pi k}$ for the harmonic $e^{i2\pi k/T_0}$.

Also, $-g(t)$ has Fourier series coefficients of $-a_k$.

From the given condition, the Fourier series coefficients of both $g\left(t-\frac{T_0}{2}\right)$ and $-g(t)$ should be equal for all $k$, i.e.

$$\begin{align}
a_k e^{-i\pi k} =& -a_k\\
a_k \left(e^{-i\pi k} + 1\right) =& 0
\end{align}$$

For even $k$s, the second factor is non-zero, therefore $a_k$ must be zero. In other words, there are no even order harmonics. (For odd $k$s, the second factor is zero, and $a_k$ may or may not be zero)

Comment: Thanks. I really dont see this details about "the shift" for function. Best.